# Printer goes beyond the bed when auto leveling

Tags: printer-building

I am trying to add auto bed leveling to my Prusa i3. When I run `G28` my printer hits the X and Y end stops properly, then it assumes X=25, Y=99 position on the bed and performs Z homing, after which it stays there. The problem is when I run `G29` then it starts following the grid points from this position and tries to go out of bed.

My settings for the grid are:

```
#define LEFT_PROBE_BED_POSITION 10
#define RIGHT_PROBE_BED_POSITION 140
#define BACK_PROBE_BED_POSITION 140
#define FRONT_PROBE_BED_POSITION 20
```

And travel limits are set to this:

```
#define X_MAX_POS 150
#define X_MIN_POS 0
#define Y_MAX_POS 150
#define Y_MIN_POS 0
#define Z_MAX_POS 220
#define Z_MIN_POS 0
```

I guess this might be relevant too:

```
#ifdef Z_SAFE_HOMING

  #define Z_SAFE_HOMING_X_POINT (X_MAX_LENGTH/2)
  #define Z_SAFE_HOMING_Y_POINT (Y_MAX_LENGTH/2)

#endif
```

Comment: What should be added to your question is the offset position of the sensor to determine the correct sensor bounds (see e.g. [How to set Z-probe boundary limits in firmware when using automatic bed leveling?](/q/8153)). Note that the presented code is somewhat dated w.r.t. current Marlin configuration, but, if correctly inserted, the printer homes in the middle of the bed dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your firmware load handles `G29` ,but here's a guess, based on information at the  [reprap wiki](http://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#G29:_Detailed_Z-Probe) .  Try using `FBLR` to force the travel limits.

> #### Parameters
>
> P Set the size of the grid that will be probed (P x P
>   points). Not supported by non-linear delta printer bed leveling. 
>   Example: G29 P4 S Set the XY travel speed between probe points (in
>   units/min)
>   D Dry-Run mode. Just evaluate the bed Topology - Don't
>   apply or clean the rotation Matrix. Useful to check the topology after
>   a first run of G29.
>   V Set the verbose level (0-4). Example: G29 V3
>   T
>   Generate a Bed Topology Report. Example: G29 P5 T for a detailed
>   report. This is useful for manual bed leveling and finding flaws in
>   the bed (to assist with part placement). Not supported by non-linear
>   delta printer bed leveling.
>   F Set the Front limit of the probing grid
>   B Set the Back limit of the probing grid.
>      L Set the Left limit of the
>   probing grid
>   R Set the Right limit of the probing grid